# How can I deploy a new version of a google apps web app using the new editor

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications

When I deployed a new version of a script using the legacy editor, the "web app meta-version" was set to that version number and the link that my users have will execute the new version.
When I use the new editor the "web app meta-version" is not updated  but a new "default meta-version" is created instead and a new ID/url is generated for it with the new version number shown there. The "web app meta-version" is left with the older numbered version of the code.
I do not want to update the links that the users have. Is there no way with the new editor to update the "web app meta-version" version number? An alternative would be to be able to set the required ID/url for the "default meta-version".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is a known issue

And it seems that Google have recognized it.

Go give this issue a ☆:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/175944464

<sup>Please don't commment with "+1", if you just click the star you will be subscribed and functions as a "+1"</sup>

Comment: many thanks. I do not seem to be able to view that issue in order to 'star" it. I get 
"Access Denied for <email address>" in a red banner when I click the link. The <email address> is the one I used to report it.

Answer (score 0):

I can now see (and have "starred") the issue number shown in iansedano's answer. However, that is a duplicate issue and the original issue to which it refers (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175811864) is inaccessible. I cannot imagine that having "starred" duplicates makes much difference to anyone responsible for resolving the original.

Comment: Sadly the issue has recurred and I have had to revert to the Legacy Editor. The new editor again has started assigning a new ID every deployment which is of course unhelpful. Pity really I was beginning to like the new editor.